# how does link clicks work in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

i need to track the email clicks and do corresponding activities.
how does the link tracking works if a user clicks on more than one link or more than one time on the same link during the wait window in the journey builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the scenes, JB sends are Triggered Emails. You can see their tracking in the 'Journey Builder' folder of the Tracking tab of the email app.

Regarding their interaction with engagement splits, the 'Have they Clicked?' engagement split is looking for at least one click - it doesnt care how many or which link was clicked, just that at least one click occurred.